# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate') when view is called from tabs, this props.navigation becomes undefined

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation, native-base, react-props

I am stuck here for past few days, tried almost everything related react-navigation but no luck.  Here is flow.
After the drawer has loaded, In Main I am calling view from Tabs, in which I am calling view of home screen,  and in Home screen, I am trying to navigate to Categories screen. but getting this error.  this.props.navigation becomes undefined in tabs.js but has value in previous screen which is main. Please help.

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
  this.state = {
    showRealApp: false
  }

}
  _onDone = () => {

    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      return <Navigator />;
    } else {
      return <AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>;
    }
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
 import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
    const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
    screen: Main,
    navigationOptions: {header: null,}
  },
  Tabss: {
      screen: Tabss,
      navigationOptions: {header: null,}
  },
   Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {header: null,}
   },
  SelectCategory: {
    screen: SelectCategory,
    navigationOptions: {header: null, }
  },

 });
   const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);
   export default App;
```

**Main.js**

`

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }
  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };
  openDrawer = () => {
  this.drawer._root.open()
  };
  render() {
   // alert(this.props.navigation)
    return (
              <Drawer
                ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
               // { data: { avatar: this.state.avatar, name: this.state.name }

               content={<Sidebar />}
                onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
                 <AppHeader
                    openDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
                />
                /////////////////// Calling Tab view///////
                 <Tabss />
                 </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Main;`
```

**Tabs.js**

```
export default class TabBars extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Tab renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab style={{backgroundColor:'#DAA520'}} />  }>
          <TabHeading={<TabHeading style={{backgroundColor: '#DAA520'}}>
            <Icon name="home" style={{ color: 'white' }} />
          </TabHeading>}>
          <Home  />
        </Tab>
      ............
      </Container>
    )}
```

**Home.js**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Button  onPress={() => 
          this.props.navigation.navigate("SelectCategory")} style= 
          {{backgroundColor:'white', width: 210, height: 50, marginBottom: 30, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}> 
          <Text style={{color: '#4169E1', fontSize: 18, fontWeight:'bold'}}> 
            Select and PLAY 
          </Text> 
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should send the props when calling a view of other screen with it.

**Main.js**

```
    render() {


    return (
              <Drawer
                ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}


               content={<Sidebar />}
                onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
                 <AppHeader
                    openDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
                />

                <Tabss data={this.props.navigation} />

                 </Drawer>
    );

  }
```

**TabBar.js**

```
    export default class TabBars extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Tab renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab style={{backgroundColor:'#DAA520'}} />  }>
          <TabHeading={<TabHeading style={{backgroundColor: '#DAA520'}}>
            <Icon name="home" style={{ color: 'white' }} />
          </TabHeading>}>
          <Home data ={this.props.data}  />
        </Tab>
      ............
      </Container>
    )}
```

**home.js**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Button   onPress= {()=> this.props.data.navigate("SelectCategory")} style= 
          {{backgroundColor:'white', width: 210, height: 50, marginBottom: 30, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}> 
          <Text style={{color: '#4169E1', fontSize: 18, fontWeight:'bold'}}> 
            Select and PLAY 
          </Text> 
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Home.js to this and see if it works:

Also, im assuming that you correctly exported your RootStack and is using it in the App.js (or if you are using reactNavigation 3.0 you correctly created your appContainer)

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
      <View>
        <Button  onPress={() => 
          navigate('SelectCategory')} 
          style= {{backgroundColor:'white', width: 210, height: 50, marginBottom: 30, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
        > 
          <Text style={{color: '#4169E1', fontSize: 18, fontWeight:'bold'}}> 
            Select and PLAY 
          </Text> 
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Still giving the same error but now before showing home. I have logged  "this.props.navigation" in home, it is giving me undefined.

Comment: Which version of react-navigation are you using? Have you correctly exported your RootStack to your App.js?

Comment: "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"

StackNavigator.js

`import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
   Main: {
    screen: Main,
    navigationOptions: {header: null,}
  },
   Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {header: null,}
   },
   SelectCategory: {
    screen: SelectCategory,
    navigationOptions: {header: null, }
  }, 
 });
  const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);
  export default App; `

Comment: did you register your app in your App.js file?

Comment: Yes I have.. 
here is my app.js render 
`render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      return <Navigator />;
    } else {
      return <AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>;
    }
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)`

Comment: are you using expo? i believe that if you are, you should register your app, expo will do it for you.. just trying to cover as much ground as i can

Comment: App.js
`export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
  this.state = {
    showRealApp: false
  }

}
  _onDone = () => {
  this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      return <Navigator />;
    } else {
      return <AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>;
    }
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)`

Comment: please edit your question and post the code there, its easier to read

Comment: I am not using expo.